maui: two different datatemplates seem to collide (value must not be null)
I am trying this:
    <cards:CarouselView >
        <cards:CarouselView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type View}">
                <StackLayout>
                    <CollectionView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionViewContent}">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="ViewModels:CollectionViewContent">
                                <Grid Padding="10,6,10,6">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=White, Default=Black}" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding PropertyName}"/>
                                    <BoxView Grid.Row="1" HeightRequest="2" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=Black, Default=White}"/>
                                    <Label Margin="0,5,0,5" TextColor="{Binding Color}" FontFamily="WuerthExtraBold" HorizontalOptions="End" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding PropertyValue}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="Hi yolonese"/>
                </StackLayout>  
            </x:Array>
        </cards:CarouselView.ItemsSource>
    </cards:CarouselView>

Its a carouselview with a collectionview inside of it. both get their own itemtemplate. However, while this does not show any errors, when i hit compile I get :

I do believe this is a false error, but if I deleted the collectionview inside the carouselview, the code works fine. If I only use the collectionview, without the carouselview wrapping it, it also works fine.
Only when the two are combined it doesnt compile.
Any ideas on what this might be?
I even set the DataType explicit, so that it wont get confused, seems to be to no avail.
Best,
J

I think you're confusing (or mixing) ItemsSource with ItemTemplate. Usually elements inside ItemsSource are objects that represent your domain, while ItemTemplate is the view that will be used to show those objects. In your example you're setting the ItemsSource of CarouselView to an array of views.

maybe, can you show me how i could get it right?

It's hard in a comment. I'm going to write an answer and edit it if needed.

Sorry, I was trying to elaborate my thoughts in an answer but there are too many missing details to give a valid explanation. Could you please explain what you need to do from a higher point of view?
Consider that if you need if you need a CarouselView with a CollectionView inside, you should have a collection of collections of CollectionViewContent. If that's not the case, probably something in your view needs to be redesigned. @innom

Well, basically I want a carouselview with differnt layouts. I want my first view to contain my already perfectly designed collection view, and the second view (swipe left) to just be a different kind of collection view with a different layout. so i would need a carouselview with 2 different layouts that both however bind to the same view model

Ok, that's more clear. By default, CollectionView applies the same DataTemplate to each view. To achieve what you need you have to use a DataTemplateSelector.
